# Using a variable to replace lines in a file with backslashes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to **add the string `%%%`** to the **beginning** of some specific lines in a text file.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
a="c:\Temp"
sed "s/$a/%%%$a/g" <File.txt
```

And this is my `File.txt` content:

```
d:\Temp
c:\Temp
e:\Temp
```

But **nothing changes** when I execute it.
I think the 'sed'  command is not finding the pattern, possibly due to the `\` backslashes in the variable `a`.
I can find the `c:\Temp` line if I use **grep** with `-F` option (to not interpret strings):

```
cat File.txt | grep -F "$a"
```

But `sed` seems not to implement such '-F` option.

Not working neither:

```
sed 's/$a/%%%$a/g' <File.txt
sed 's/"$a"/%%%"$a"/g' <File.txt
```

I have found similar threads about replacing with `sed`, but they don't refer to variables.

How can I **replace the desired lines by using a variable** adding them the `%%%` char string?

EDIT: It would be fine that the `$a` variable could be entered via parameter when calling the script, so it will be assigned like:

```
a=$1
```

Comment: Don't you need sed -i to edit in place?  Also probably need "C:\\Temp"

Comment: Indeed, I need it, @JohnC. But it doesn't matter very much, because I could use some redirection '>File2.txt' or so.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
a='c:\\Temp'  # single quotes
sed "s/$a/%%%$a/g" <File.txt  # double quotes
```

Output:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:sed jcreasey$ sh x.sh
d:\Temp
e:\Temp
%%%c:\Temp
```

You need the double slash '\' to escape the '\'.
The single quotes won't expand the variables.
So you escape the slash in single quotes and pass it into the double quotes.

Of course you could also just do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/\(.*Temp\)/%%%&/' <File.txt
```

If you want to get input from the command line you have to allow for the fact that \ is an escape character there too.  So the user needs to type 'c:\\' or the interpreter will just wait for another character.  Then once you get it, you will need to escape it again. (printf %q).

```
#!/bin/sh
b=`printf "%q" $1`
sed "s/\($b\)/%%% &/" < File.txt
```

Comment: John, please, read my edit to the original post. We must count with the posiblity to enter `$a` variable as a parameter. I am checking it right now.

Comment: Since your input is `$1`, have you tried to see what you get in your script?  For example, if you type `YourScript C:\Temp`, your script `YourScript` will receive `C:Temp`, not `C:\Temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your script with a positional parameter of $1

```
#!/bin/bash  
a="$1"
cat <file path>|sed "s/"$1"/%%%"$1"/g" > "temporary file"
```

Now whenever you want sed to find  "c:\Temp" you need to use your script command line as follows

```
  bash <my executing script> c:\\\\Temp
```

The first backslash will make bash interpret any backslashes that follows therefore what will be save in variable "a" in your executing script is "c:\\Temp". Now substituting  this variable in sed will cause sed to interpret 1 backlash since the first backslash in this variable will cause sed to start interpreting the other backlash.

when you Open your temporary file you will see:

```
d:\Temp
%%%c:\Temp
e:\Temp
```

Comment: An interesting approach to the problem. Maybe I could convert "\" to "\\" inside the script, before calling sed

Comment: seems like a good idea..note I made an edit to my positional parameter $1 "c:\\\Temp" to "c:\\\\Temp" (double backslashes for 1 backslash)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having has to do with substitution of your variable providing a regular expression looking for a literal `c:Temp` with the `\` interpreted as an escape **by the shell**. There are a number of workarounds. Seeing the comments and having worked through the possibilities, the following will allow the unquoted entry of the search term:

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate that needed input is given on the command line
[ -n "$1" -a "$2" ] || {
    printf "Error: insufficient input. Usage:  %s <term> <file>\n" "${0//*\//}" >&2
    exit 1
}

## validate that the filename given is readable
[ -r "$2" ] || {
    printf "Error: file not readable '%s'\n" "$2" >&2
    exit 1
}

a="$1"        # assign a
filenm="$2"   # assign filename

## test and fix the search term entered
[[ "$a" =~ '/' ]] || a="${a/:/:\\}"  # test if \ removed by shell, if so replace
a="${a/\\/\\\\}"                     # add second \

sed -e "s/$a/%%%$a/g" "$filenm"      # call sed with output to stdout
```

**Usage:**

```
$ bash sedwinpath.sh c:\Temp dat/winpath.txt
d:\Temp
%%%c:\Temp
e:\Temp
```

**Note:** This allows both `single-quoted` or `unquoted` entry of the dos path search term. To **edit in place** use `sed -i`. Additionally, the `[[` operator and `=~` operator are limited to bash.

---

I could have sworn the original question said replace, but to append, just as you suggest in the comments. I have updated the code with:

```
sed -e "s/$a/%%%$a/g" "$filenm"
```

Which provides the new output:

```
$ bash sedwinpath.sh c:\Temp dat/winpath.txt
d:\Temp
%%%c:\Temp
e:\Temp
```

**Remember:** If you want to edit the file **in place** use `sed -i` or `sed -i.bak` which will edit the actual file (and if `-i.bak` is given create a backup of the original in `originalname.bak`). Let me know if that is not what you intended and I'm happy to edit again.

Comment: A very good answer, David, but I think you forgot to append the original line to `%%%`. Maybe you should `sed -e "s/$a/%%%&/g" "$filenm"`?

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. You want to append `%%%` instead of replace? If so, yes, I screwed the pooch, because I just had it replace the line with `%%%`. I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Well, both things are correct: I want to prepend the string `%%%`, but I was pretending to do it by replacing `$a` with `%%%$a`.

Comment: I do that to myself all the time... Just pick the form that works best. If you run into a problem. Drop a comment and I'm happy to help.